# Are there any hooks for the `yarn remove [package]` command? (Hooks similar to postinstall)

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I need to run a script after

- `yarn add [package]`
- `yarn remove [package]`
- `yarn upgrade [package]`
- `yarn install`

`postinstall` is triggered after `yarn add`, `yarn upgrade` and `yarn install`. However, it does not seem to work with `yarn remove`. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean `postremove` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, `postremove` does not work. I created an issue with yarn, they closed it saying to simply upgrade to 2.4. https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8547#event-4202158721

Comment: Have you already eliminated https://www.npmjs.com/package/postinstall-postinstall as a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported by Yarn v1, Yarn v2 supports this now.

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8547#event-4202158721
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8498#event-4202173689